# using where and inner join in mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have three tables.

**locations**

```
ID   | NAME | TYPE |
1    | add1 | stat |
2    | add2 | coun | 
3    | add3 | coun |
4    | add4 | coun | 
5    | add5 | stat |
```

**schools**

```
 ID | NAME  
 1  | sch1     
 2  | sch2
 3  |sch3
```

**school_locations**

```
 ID |LOCATIONS_ID |SCHOOL_ID
 1  | 1           |1
 2  | 2           |2
 3  | 3           |3
```

Here the table locations contains all the locations of the application.Locations for school are called by ID's.

when i use the query

```
select locations.name from locations where type="coun";
```

it displays names with type "coun"

But I want to display locations.name where only school_locations have type="coun"

i tried following queries, but none seems to be working

```
select locations.name 
from locations 
where type="coun" 
inner join school_locations 
   on locations.id=school_locations.location_id 
inner join schools 
   on school_locations.school.id=schools.id;
```

and

```
select locations.name 
from locations 
inner join school_locations 
   on locations.id=school_locations.location_id 
inner join schools 
   on school_locations.school.id=schools.id  where type="coun";
```

is it possible to use multiple inner joins in queries, or is there another way?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
    SELECT `locations`.`name`
      FROM `locations`
INNER JOIN `school_locations`
        ON `locations`.`id` = `school_locations`.`location_id`
INNER JOIN `schools`
        ON `school_locations`.`school_id` = `schools_id`
     WHERE `type` = 'coun';
```

the `WHERE` clause has to be at the end of the statement

Comment: are the backticks needed in msql?

Comment: no, but i like having them there, it avoids problems with strange table or column names (e.g. select, count, a%b, etc.) and is more foolproof

Comment: It also, unfortunately, makes the query non-ANSI-compliant, potentially causing problems if you try to migrate the query to another database. The proper way of delimiting identifiers is with "doublequotes", but MySQL doesn't support this by default; you have to set ANSI_QUOTES in SQL_MODE to get that. Of course that then messes up your string literal "coun", which should regardless of SQL_MODE be written with single quotes.

Comment: interesting, didn’t know that about backticks vs. quotation marks (i only work with mysql). and uh, you’re right about single quotes for strings (copy-paste error from the question asker’s code)

Comment: Gee, I was stuck putting the `WHERE` statement before the `INNER JOIN`. I used regular single quotes.

Comment: To add to this, if you are joining large tables you can run this as an `INNER JOIN (SELECT * WHERE type = 'coun') AS subset ON locations.id = school_locations.location_id` to first grab a subset of the large table being joined, presuming there's some criteria you can use in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT Locations.Name, Schools.Name
FROM Locations
INNER JOIN School_Locations ON School_Locations.Locations_Id = Locations.Id
INNER JOIN Schools ON School.Id = Schools_Locations.School_Id
WHERE Locations.Type = "coun"
```

You can join Locations to School_Locations and then School_Locations to School.  This forms a set of all related Locations and Schools, which you can then widdle down using the WHERE clause to those whose Location is of type "coun."

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    (
      SELECT
          `NAME`
      FROM
          locations
      WHERE
          ID = school_locations.LOCATION_ID
    ) as `NAME`
FROM
     school_locations
WHERE
     (
      SELECT
          `TYPE`
      FROM
          locations
      WHERE
          ID = school_locations.LOCATION_ID
     ) = 'coun';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use as many joins as you want, however, the more you use the more it will impact performance

Comment: that doesn’t answer his question

Comment: I beg to differ, see the last sentence in the question.  Sure I didn't answer the whole question, but I felt that one of the other answers covered that.

Comment: But then according to stackoverflow etiquette this should be a comment to that particular answer. Thanks for understanding.