# Having trouble with simple inner join in mysql

Tags: mysql

So I basicly have a database that looks like this:

```
card_types
id    description    price
1     Card1           1.00
2     Card2           2.00
3     Card3           3.00

card_occasions
id    occasion
1     birthday
2     graduation
3     thank you
4     other

type_occasions
ID    TypeID   OccasionID
1     1        1
2     1        2
3     1        4
4     2        3
```

I am trying to do an inner join using **WHERE card_type.ID = 1** resulting in a similar output but I have no idea where to begin.

Example output:

```
card_occasion.ID   card_occasions.Name
1                  birthday
2                  graduation
4                  other
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: Thats the problem I don't know what to do for the query.

Comment: You want to join all 3 tables?

Comment: I just want the results listed above using the WHERE card_type.ID = 1. I'm pretty sure that would require joining all three tables in some way or another.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using where and inner join in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392479/using-where-and-inner-join-in-mysql)

Comment: Is this what you want
SELECT co.id, co.name
FROM card_types AS ct
LEFT JOIN type_occasions AS to ON (ct.id = to.TypeID)
LEFT JOIN card_occasions AS co ON (co.id = to.ID)
WHERE ct.id = 1

Comment: Your question contains some confusing typos. You should check if you spell table and field names consistently. However I think I know what you want :) - see my answer below.

Comment: This question is a good example how to NOT use Stack Overflow. A "question" like "Having trouble with simple inner join in mysql", and four nearly identical answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since type_occasions already owns the typeid, you don't need to join the type table.

```
SELECT o.id, o.occassion
FROM card_occasions o
INNER JOIN type_occasions t ON t.occassionid = o.id
WHERE t.typeid = 1
```

Comment: I don't understand why it's not your answer which won points!

Comment: Sorry about such a poorly written question. I am on a deadline with this project I'm working on and didn't have much time to write it out/explain it. I'm still learning this MySQL joining stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You begin with the table where you want values. After [`Join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/join.html) the table you need to make the relation.

```
SELECT card_occasions.id, card_occasions.occasion
FROM card_occasion co
INNER JOIN type_occasions to ON (to.OccasionID = co.id)
                                               ^ the relation between two table
WHERE ct.ID = 1
```

Comment: Why do you think your answer has a significant value in addition to mine?

Comment: Most likely several people started writing answers at the same time so its a reason for multiple near identical answers. happens all the time in SO site.

Comment: It's a timing problem for my answer, I think it's your answer which should have won points

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for beeing a bit rude.

Comment: they are all essentially the same answer. But Mulmoth did have some added detail. So I will give him the points instead.

Comment: No problem for me. It's Mulmoth who is Pernicket. But I excuse him.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.id,A.occasion FROM card_occasions A JOIN type_occasions B ON B.OccasionID= A.id AND B.TypeID=1
```

Comment: @user1831430 It's not about what is "working", but what answers your question the best.
Your question was about "using WHERE card_type.ID = 1".

Comment: I saw this answer first. I didn't see the others until I refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

And if you really want to link all three tables for reason we don't see here you may use this method. This starts linking from the type_occasion table to appropriate "basic data" tables.

```
Select
  typeo.OccasionID, co.occasion as Name
From type_occasion typeo
  JOIN card_type ct ON (typeo.TypeID=ct.id)
  JOIN card_occasion co ON (typeo.OccasionID=co.id)
Where
  typeo.TypeID=1
  -- ct.id=1
```